# Program to display CSV nicely from clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, clipboard, csv

I'm occationaly dealing with `CSV` files. I was wondering if there's a program that displays the CSV nicely in an Excel-like format (bonus for enabling sorting and searching) **on the fly** without saving the CSV to file and then opening it in excel. Preferably, it should be able to fetch the data from the clipboard and display it in an Excel-like format

My current workflow is: look at CSV piece of data in a text file -> copy it to Excel -> click on "convert text to rows" menu -> select comma as separator -> examine data. If there's a piece of software that would save me the trouble that would be nice.

Comment: +1 Interesting question because I've always just used Excel.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why can't you just go into excel and type Ctrl-V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/index.html) is a free program that allows you to edit, merge and convert these files with ease.

Here's what it can do:

- column sort and global sort
- edit, add, insert and delete items
- import
- change separator
- add, delete columns
- rearrange column order
- save selection of rows and columns
- save filtered items
- save with double quotes
- search and replace
- filter items
- remove duplicates
- append and merge files
- add prefix and suffix
- split and join columns
- export to HTML, Excel, Word, XML and more
- column search

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) is all you need:

> CSVed is an easy and powerful CSV file editor, you can manipulate any
>   CSV file, separated with any separator.

[image]